Bring JSESSIONID in Tomcat Application and JSESSIONID in Spring Boot together
I am working on bringing two apps together sessionwise.
So the prefered state is one JSESSIONID, which both apps - one is tomcat the other one can understand.
I found that the tomcat-JSESSIONID: FE3C8E5C2999349F681A416C565EB7D7 is differing in the format from the other Spring-JSESSIONID: MWQ2NDQzYzYtZjViZi00M2NhLTk3NzUtZGQ1ZDkzOGVhODg0 which is an Base 64 encoded UUID.
The question is now how to proceed. Either I change how the tomcat-JSESSIONID is created or I change which JsessionId Spring is accepting. Because if I change the Spring-JSESSIONID to the same format of the Tomcat-JSESSIONID it won't accept it and dispatches the Spring prefered format (Base64 decoded uuid)
I could now change the logic in tomcat or the one in spring, I am not sure what would be the most feasable way (I guess spring, but how?)

What you are aiming is impossible as per servlet specification; two contexts cannot have same session. refer: https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/jakarta-servlet-spec-5.0.html#session-scope
